# Issues obtaining Fo in DIY Imaging Fluorometer

Tags: plant-physiology, imaging, signal-processing

I have successfully built an imaging fluorometer at home (see project details [here](https://hackaday.io/project/174580-a-diy-imaging-fluorometer)) and so far is working amazingly well.

But I am having serious issues in obtaining Fo to calculate Fv/Fm (Fm-Fo)/Fm. The reason is less technical than theoretical, as after scouting dozens of academic papers all I can find are contradicting accounts as to how to set up the fluorometer to effectively obtain an Fo value.

Without Fo, the Fv/Fm values of all plants I have analysed range around ± 0.90 which is way above the usual 0.83 the literature cites as an unstressed plant. If the number were below 0.83, I would believe the plants are stressed, but a higher number clearly indicates my setup is not correct.

Most literature states that the measuring beam must be of the order of < 1 μmoles m−2 s−1 to avoid eliciting any photosynthetic rate. The reason for the literature to be so scant about this protocol is that 99% of fluorescence research is done with commercial fluorometers and researchers don't need to adjust parameters as they are adjusted by the software. There seems to be a bit of esoteric mistery around these fluorometer parameters, probably due to some commercial sensitiveness.

Under my setup, using a measuring light of < 1 μmoles m−2 s−1 elicits a signal of 0.3 on the camera, while the saturating pulse can be over 100 (0-255 scale or 8 bits) and above depending on intensity. Calculating Fv/Fm using these numbers gives a number above 0.98 which is clearly wrong. Increasing the camera exposure does not help.

Another issue is that we are talking about fluorescence imaging and not the traditional photodiode based fluorometer which is closer to the source and way more sensitive. A camera is far away from the subject and increasing too much exposure leads to noise, etc.

Then again, I do not think this is a technical issue, as I've got the feeling the measuring light of the commercial imaging fluorometers is much stronger than otherwise stated.

Has anybody dealt with this specific issue?

Answer (score 1):

This [paper](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s11099-005-0062-6)<sup>1</sup> gives a definition of all the various parameters. F<sub>0</sub> (that's F<sub>zero</sub>, not F letter "o" I think) is defined as the dark state fluorescence. There is a second parameter F<sub>0</sub><sup>'</sup> that is the light state fluorescence.

F<sub>0</sub> would be your ground-state with minimal induced fluorescence, it seems that this might require "overnight in the dark" for true measurement values. Measure the fluorescence with the measurement (far-red I think) light turned on. You should then apply a saturating pulse of actinic light to measure F<sub>M</sub>. You should also determine the background from your rig using reads taken with no sample in place and with and without measurement light turned on. This [paper](https://academic.oup.com/jxb/article/51/345/659/652534)<sup>2</sup> provides a description:

> The calculation of fluorescence parameters is probably best explained by reference to a typical experimental trace (Fig. 1). Under field conditions, an experiment of this type may not always be appropriate, however, most of the parameters can still be calculated. The measurement is initiated by switching on the measuring light, giving a measure of the F<sub>o</sub> (minimal) level of fluorescence. A saturating flash of light is then applied, allowing the measurement of F<sub>m</sub> in the dark‐adapted state (⁠
> F<sub>o</sub><sup>m</sup>
> ⁠). Following on from this, an actinic light is applied and, at appropriate intervals, further saturating flashes are applied. From each of these, a value for F<sub>m</sub><sup>'</sup>
> ⁠, the fluorescence maximum in the light, can be measured. The steady‐state value of fluorescence immediately prior to the flash is termed F<sub>t</sub>. After a flash, removal of actinic light (preferably whilst simultaneously giving a far‐red light) allows measurement of F<sub>m</sub><sup>'</sup>
> ⁠.

1: Lichtenthaler *et al*. Photosynthetica volume 43, pages 379–393 (2005)

2: Maxwell and Johnson. Journal of Experimental Botany, Volume 51, Issue 345, April 2000, Pages 659–668

Comment: I am well aware of those papers and they don't answer the fundamental question, nor does your answer. In the meantime, I have found the answer to my question but I need to test it before posting my answer here.

Comment: @MaykeSantos - I read your question to ask how to set F0, due to this bit "*But I am having serious issues in obtaining Fo to calculate Fv/Fm (Fm-Fo)/Fm.*" I don't see any other questions in your post (other than last sentence). If you could solve F0, then your problem would disappear. Can you calculate F0' as a proxy?  the literature suggests that this is a reasonable substitute. I doubt the measurement light on commercial instruments is strong as calibration is a common part of set-up when purchasing these sorts of instruments.

Comment: yes, the question is how to calculate F0 in a Chl imaging fluorometer system, that is different to most common photodiode-fibre fluorometers. There is a long paper about how to calculate F0' (not F0) as a proxy, but that's different and it can be achieved with far red light. Now, to answer the question itself, my problem is light modulation. I need to apply a very strong light pulse but at a much higher frequency (below 300us) in order to avoid eliciting photosynthesis. The answer is in Oxborough 2004

Comment: @MaykeSantos - you should edit that into your question, as it isn't clearly stated what you are actually looking for. 300 us is very short, you might be able to do it with a shutter mechanism, but you would need a very fast processor controller. You might be better asking for migration to the [electronics SE](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I will leave it as it is. Thanks.